# Oracle Trigger: Insert into Transaction Entity New Row Upon Update, Insert of Account Entity

Tags: oracle, jdbc, plsql, triggers, database-trigger

I'm a newbie to SQL and I'm having a real hard time setting up this trigger.  It's for a Bank Console JDBC sort of thing.

I have a schema with three entities, USER, ACCOUNT, and TRANSACTION. I want to keep track of all the changes a user makes to one of her accounts by inserting a new row into my transaction entity, which has columns of

1. id, which I'm handling with a sequence,
2. user_id (referencing a foreign key stored in the accounts entity),
3. account_id (referencing the account entity's primary key),
4. a time stamp, (for which I'm using Oracle's CURRENT_TIMESTAMP function),
5. and a transaction-type, which is either of 'deposit' or 'withdrawal'.

Here's how my Trigger looks right now.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ADD_TX
ON ACCOUNT
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE old_balance number, new_balance number, transaction_type varchar2(100);
BEGIN
  transaction_type := CASE WHEN :NEW.balance < :OLD.balance THEN 'WITHDRAWAL' ELSE 'DEPOSIT' END;
  INSERT INTO TRANSACTIONS VALUES(TRANSACTION_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, :NEW.USER_ID, :NEW.id, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, :NEW.account_type, transaction_type);
   end if; 
END;
/
```

Any guidance would be most appreciated

Comment: Please describe what's wrong with your current code. Any error messages?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might do the job:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER add_tx AFTER
  INSERT OR UPDATE ON account
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO transactions VALUES (
    transaction_id_seq.NEXTVAL,
    :new.user_id,
    :new.id,
    current_timestamp,
    :new.account_type,
      CASE
        WHEN :new.balance <:old.balance  THEN 'WITHDRAWAL'
        ELSE 'DEPOSIT'
      END
  );    
END;
/
```

Though, I'd suggest you to name ALL columns you're inserting to; the way you wrote it, it is unclear which value goes into which column, and such a code might (and probably will) break, some day.

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you @Littlefoot!